# Rufus Scheduler not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rufus-scheduler

I want to do something simple with the gem rufus-scheduler:
https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler

but, i can't get it to work.

I have a regular rails app. I created a .rb file:

```
# test_rufus_scheduler.rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus/scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

scheduler.in '1s' do
  puts "hello world"
end
```

Then, when I try ruby test_rufus_scheduler.rb, nothing happens. Am i doing it right? gem list shows rufus-scheduler.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your script exits right away please try to add

`scheduler.join`

at the end. Please note that it's different when running the script stand alone and via rails. See the [README](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#schedulerjoin) for detailled information.

Answer (score 2):

Add the below lines to your apache2 config and restart your apache2 server

```
RailsAppSpawnerIdleTime 0
PassengerMinInstances 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution to this [here](https://richonrails.com/articles/background-tasks-with-rufus-scheduler) (which also is in sync to [Ajet's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1589532/ajet) answer above).

> Production servers require a bit of additional setup. On most production web servers, idle Ruby processes are killed. In order for Rufus to work, you'll need to stop this from happening. For Passenger/Nginx you can copy the following code below to your **nginx.conf** config file for your website after the line that says **passenger_enabled on;**.

**nginx.conf:**

```
passenger_spawn_method direct;
passenger_min_instances 1;
passenger_pool_idle_time 0;
```

Comment: I'm using Amazon Linux AMI as my server for EC2.  I don't see the file nginx.conf when I remote to the server.  I do have a passenger file /etc/init.d/passenger.  Do I modify this file?  Where would I add the information you listed in your solution?